# Parse object through Navigation from adapter to fragment Kotlin using Parcelize

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a list of movies (`RecyclerView`) and when a movie is clicked it goes to another fragment where the movie clicked is displayed. I want to send the data of the movie object through the navigation from the adapter to the fragment using `Parcelize` but i'm getting stuck on this.

My Movie data class:

```
@Parcelize
data class Movie(
    @SerializedName("poster_path") val poster_path : String,
    @SerializedName("adult") val adult : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("overview") val overview : String,
    @SerializedName("release_date") val release_date : String,
    @SerializedName("genre_ids") val genre_ids : List<Int>,
    @SerializedName("id") val id : Int,
    @SerializedName("original_title") val original_title : String,
    @SerializedName("original_language") val original_language : String,
    @SerializedName("title") val title : String,
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path") val backdrop_path : String,
    @SerializedName("popularity") val popularity : Double,
    @SerializedName("vote_count") val vote_count : Int,
    @SerializedName("video") val video : Boolean,
    @SerializedName("vote_average") val vote_average : Double
) : Parcelable
```

My nav_graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/MoviesFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/MoviesFragment"
        android:name="com.example.level6rg.ui.MoviesFragment"
        android:label="Movies"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_movies">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_MoviesFragment_to_SingleMovieFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SingleMovieFragment">
        </action>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SingleMovieFragment"
        android:name="com.example.level6rg.ui.SingleMovieFragment"
        android:label="Movie"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_single_movie">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SingleMovieFragment_to_MoviesFragment"
            app:destination="@id/MoviesFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="Movie"
            app:argType="com.example.level6rg.model.Movie" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

My MovieAdapter:

```
class MovieAdapter(private val movies: List<Movie>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val imageBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/"
        private val binding = ItemMovieBinding.bind(itemView)

        fun databind(movie: Movie) {
            Glide.with(itemView).load(imageBaseUrl + movie.poster_path).into(binding.ivMovie);
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val movie = movies[position]
        holder.databind(movies[position])
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // Navigate to SingleMovieFragment and parse movie object...
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movies.size
    }

//    class OnClickListener(val clickListener: (movie: Movie) -> Unit) {
//        fun onClick(movie: Movie) = clickListener(movie)
//    }

}
```

I've read about `safe args` as well but I got stuck on the implementation

Comment: https://developersbreach.com/pass-data-using-navigationcomponent-in-android-with-kotlin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a safe arg, you need to choose Custom Parcalable, give your parcelable class and retrieve it in destination.

Take a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3nRZEbkWks&ab_channel=CodinginFlow